# How to store form values in data() object?

Tags: jquery, forms, dom

Is there an easy way to store form data in a `data()` object after submit?

Suppose this is my form:

```
<form id='myform'>  
<input type='text' name='bar' value='lorem'/>  
<input type='text name='foo' value='ipsum'/>  
</form>
```

After submit the data should be stored like this:

```
$("#myform").data('bar','lorem');  
$("#myform").data('foo','ipsum');
```

Comment: Just to let you know, I just found a jQuery method for this: form.serialize(). I've updated my post with some new info.

Answer (score 3):

You may do something like this:

```
$('#myform').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // don't submit the form
    var form = $(this); // store it for later reference
    form.children('input').each(function() {
        form.data($(this).attr('name'), $(this).attr('value'));
    });
});
```

**Edit**: My code had some errors in it (`getChildren` » `children`, `myform` » `#myform`) – I've now corrected it.

Note that this script doesn't submit the form. You may add [some nifty ajax](http://docs.jquery.com/API/1.3/Ajax) to do that :)
http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serialize

**Update**: Actually, jQuery already has this functionality built-in: [`form.serialize()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serialize). It returns a valid query string:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="radio" value="A" name="foo" checked="checked" /> A<br />
    <input type="radio" value="B" name="foo" /> B
    <input type="text" name="bar" value="Bla bla" />
</form>
<script>
var queryString = $('#myForm').serialize(); //foo=A&bar=Bla+bla
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't deal with select and textarea, nor if form was submitted via a button/image.
It also doesn't address state/selection - it wasn't mentioned, but I'm guessing that the OP only wants *selected* radio & checkbox values, not all values - and in either case values would need to be a list or array?

Comment: You're right, but I just pointed bartclaeys in the right direction (IMHO). I'll update the code soon, though.

Comment: Thx Moff! Still requires a lot of code (if I want to add selects etc). Thought there was something around like SerializeToDataObject.